# What does script shutdown means?

Tags: php, oop, destructor

I am new to OOP PHP and learning from [php.net](http://php.net/). But one thing that is confusing me is that what does

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

means? What does script shutdown means in the destructor section of the following reference link?

Reference link http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: The actual quote is: *"The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence."*

Comment: **Shutdown script** is also there below few lines.

Comment: PHP code only lives as long as it is required for executing the script. Then the application is destroyed/shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script ends, i.e. when all its code has been executed and PHP has arrived at the last line of your code, the PHP instance which is executing your script is being shut down. That means all memory allocations for all variables are freed, all open resources (e.g. database connections) are closed, all remaining open file handles are closed and so on. It is cleaning up whatever state your script created.

You can hook some code into that which will run during this shutdown phase (or as soon as the object in question is being discarded) to do whatever custom cleanup you might want to do.

Comment: **When your script ends, i.e. when all its code has been executed and PHP has arrived at the last line of your code, the PHP instance which is executing your script is being shut down**.By PHP Instance you mean PHP interpreter ?

Comment: Yes. An instance of the PHP interpreter is spun up for each script you run, and then shut down when it's done.

Comment: It's called by PHP when it cleans up (discards) the object.

Comment: I am providing my confusion in two parts in Comment Ok. Please read them and answer me please

Comment: **(Comment Part One)**Let suppose there are two objects **Obj1** and **Obj2** both are instance of class **Objector** and there is also a destructor method inside **Objector** class. So during the creation of **Obj1** and **Obj2** both registered their own destructors at the time of instantiation. And suppose we need **Obj1** a bit to be used in the script during the execution but we need **Obj2** to be used for long during the execution and both are in one php file.

Comment: **(Comment Part Two)**So whether the destructor of the **Obj1** will be called first after its job is completed to clean up **Obj1**'s all related data because we don't need it any more but **Obj2** destructor will not be called because it is still needed in the script execution. So my question is **Whether destructor of each object is called at their own completion ? {or} Whther the destructor is called at once for both(or all objects) by php interpreter before the script shutdown ?**

Comment: @NinjaBoy The destructor of an object is called when that object is being cleaned up. If you remove all references to an object at runtime (`unset`, variables go out of scope or any other way), the object becomes eligible for garbage collection. When GC triggers exactly is up to PHP, but conceivably sometime before the end of your script that object will be garbage collected and its destructor invoked. At the end of the script, *everything* will be garbage collected.

Comment: What does GC mean ?

Comment: Garbage Collection.

Comment: So you mean that the object(s) becomes Garbage once its/their job is completed and placed in the GC AND at the script shutdown the GC is cleaned up and destructor method of each instance(if provided in the class for its instances) is called to remove all the data related to the object(s). **Result:** The destructor is called by php interpreter after the cleanup of the object's GC and then the script is shutdown. Is that story according to my sense is right ?

Comment: GC is something that runs as needed, it may be during a script's execution, but definitely also at shutdown time. Calling an object's destructor is part of the GC of an object. E.g. if PHP notices it runs low on memory, it'll start a GC in the hopes of freeing up some memory; when it finds an object it can discard during that GC cycle, it'll invoke its destructor.

Comment: So calling destructor depends on the object use, ha ? If not needed, thrown to GC, if memory is low for php, then on the spot object's destructors are called and those objects are removed from GC. I got you thank you